# Weird jQuery DataTables Initialization Behaviour

Tags: jquery, datatables-1.10

I have the following code.  And I wonder why it works in one way but not the other.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<title>Chart</title>
<link href="./css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="./js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script>
/*
// THIS BLOCK DOES NOT WORK
var tbldata;

$(document).ready
(
        function()
        {
                tbldata = $("#tbldata").DataTable();
        }
);
*/

// THIS SINGLE LINE WORKS
var tbldata = $("#tbldata").DataTable();
</script>
</head>
<body>
        <div>
                <table id="tbldata">
                        <thead></thead>
                        <tbody></tbody>
                </table>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It gives me the following error if I uncomment the block which I marked as not working and comment out the single line which works.

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined
    at V (http://192.168.33.10:5000/static/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js:65:443)
    at va (http://192.168.33.10:5000/static/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js:70:61)
    at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:5000/static/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js:91:148)
    at Function.each (http://192.168.33.10:5000/static/js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js:2:2815)
    at r.each (http://192.168.33.10:5000/static/js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js:2:1003)
    at r.m [as dataTable] (http://192.168.33.10:5000/static/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js:82:388)
    at r.h.fn.DataTable (http://192.168.33.10:5000/static/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js:166:245)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://192.168.33.10:5000/static/test.html:30:45)
    at j (http://192.168.33.10:5000/static/js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js:2:29568)
    at k (http://192.168.33.10:5000/static/js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js:2:29882) undefined
```

Comment: As far as I know, The block which you have commented must work and the single line must not work. If its the other way around this is **Weird**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When calling the DataTables initializer without any options, it expects a populated `thead` so it can try to detect columns and their attributes.

Add at least one `<th>` element to your thead, and then the commented code will work.

The uncommented line isn't *really* working. At the point the javascript runs, the element does not yet exist on the page! So the selector grabs 0 elements and the initializer is not really running, thus, no error.

Alternatively (and my preferred method of initializing DTs for the most part)... give your initializer an array of column definition(s).

```
$('#mytable').DataTable({
  columns: [{ title: 'First Name', data: 'FirstName' }] //etc, etc...
})
```

Comment: faced this issue earlier. yes you are right,Initializing table without any column shouldn't work...But the question still remain the same why single line is working!! why isn't that breaking.

Comment: I explained that in the last paragraph of my answer. It /isn't/ really working, it's just not throwing an error. The JS is running before the element exists. Selector picks up zero elements, so the DataTable initializer doesn't run. Ergo, no error.

Comment: @BLSully true, +1

Comment: That is exactly the answer I am looking for.  Now everything fits in its place.  Thanks!  :)